# Odd Issue Downloading XML From URL

Tags: c#, xml, ssis

I am trying to load data from RSS feeds into a SQL Server database using SSIS and am running into issues connecting.

Example URL: `https://ecf.akb.uscourts.gov/cgi-bin/rss_outside.pl` (Can connect just fine from a web browser.)

I tried using this site as a template,https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3141/importing-xml-documents-using-sql-server-integration-services/ , and everything went well, I was able to connect and even generate an .xsd file, but when I went to run it, I got a warning about the SSL\TSL certificate. I also tried using the built in Web Service task, but also ran into issues trying to download the WSLD file with the certificate.

Trying another avenue, based on these two sites, [SSIS download from http - error SSL certification response obtained from server not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43495703/ssis-download-from-http-error-ssl-certification-response-obtained-from-server) and http://palkotools.blogspot.com/2011/06/tutorial-how-to-import-rss-feeds-into.html I instead tried using a C# Script task to download the XML data into a file, before attempting to process.

Using this example feed URL, the code worked just fine:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFile(@"http://feeds.thehollywoodgossip.com/TheHollywoodGossip?format=xml", @"C:\RSS\RSSFile.xml");
```

However, when I try with the URL I need form the court, it fails:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFile(@"https://ecf.akb.uscourts.gov/cgi-bin/rss_outside.pl?format=xml", @"C:\RSS\RSSFile.xml");
```

**Is there something different\wrong with the court's URL?** I am a total C# novice, so I *hope* this is something incredibly simple. Do any of you see what I am doing wrong or needs to be different from the example Hollywood gossip URL?

Thanks!

Edit: This is the error that gets returned with the court URL

```
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? I had no issue downloading from that url using WebClient.

Comment: @jira, are you saying the second one, akb.uscourts.gov, worked fine as is? I added the error to the post body as what was thorwn is too big for a comment.

Comment: Yes the second link works fine. Your  error is due to something else.

Comment: Weird, I just tried a different computer, later version of VS, and still got the same thing as I did above. 

From a blank Script Task, all I did was add ```using System.Net;``` at the top and then switch the URL between the red arrows as shown here: https://imgur.com/DSM8QPT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this code at the first line:

```cs
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

Comment: hah! That did it, thanks @scrappy. I guess the security problems with the default tasks I was using earlier were caused by the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try following using xml linq.  Not every entry has a href :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Net;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string URL = "http://feeds.thehollywoodgossip.com/TheHollywoodGossip?format=xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(URL);
            XElement feed = doc.Root;
            XNamespace ns = feed.GetDefaultNamespace();
            List<Entry> entries = feed.Elements(ns + "entry").Select(x => new Entry()
            {
                id = (string)x.Element(ns + "id"),
                published = (string)x.Element(ns + "published"),
                updated = (DateTime)x.Element(ns + "updated"),
                href = (string)x.Descendants(ns + "href").FirstOrDefault(),
                title = (string)x.Element(ns + "title"),
                content = (string)x.Element(ns + "content"),
                category = (string)x.Element(ns + "category"),
                author = (string)x.Element(ns + "author")
            }).ToList();

        }
    }
    public class Entry
    {
        public string id {get;set;}
        public string published {get;set;}
        public DateTime updated {get;set;}
        public string href {get;set;}
        public string title {get;set;}
        public string content {get;set;}
        public string category {get;set;}
        public string author { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: this looks like it was trying to parse the gossip website XML, and not download it to a file. The issue I had was with the court's URL, and it turns out I just needed to add a line about the security protocol.

Comment: You can save to a file by just using doc.Save(filename);  Doesn't look like website needs any security.